# Attempt To Index A Nil Value Computercraft MC

Tags: lua, minecraft, computercraft

```
local sideIn = "front"

rednet.open("back")

while true do
    if disk.isPresent(sideIn) then
        term.clear()
        local code = fs.open("disk/passcode.lua", "r").readAll()
            if code == nil then
                local code = 0
            else
                code = tonumber(code)
            end
        if code == level then
            disk.eject(sideIn)
            rednet.send(16,"1")
        else
            disk.eject(sideIn)
        end
    else 
        os.queueEvent("randomEvent")
        os.pullEvent()
    end
end
```

If i run the program with a disk in, it works.

But if i run it THEN insert the disk I get an error:

`startup:11: attempt to index a nil value`

if someone can help, i would apreciate that

Comment: Probably `fs.open` returns `nil`

Comment: no idea if it has anything to do with your crash but I think you would want to leave out the word `local` at `local code = 0`. because now you make a new variable called code and after that do nothing with it

Comment: What version of minecraft and what version of computercraft are you using?

The variable `level` is not defined anywhere in this code snippet.

Also, did you name your script 'startup'? Because the error is in the startup script. You should be careful when writing scripts to be used as startup programs.